# how to upload product image using mws (amazon) using xml

Tags: amazon-mws

I have create xml for proudct image upload but it give me error

XML Parsing Error at Line 11, Column 128: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ImageType'. No child element is expected at this point.

here my xml file

Please check where to change to solve the error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
            <Header>
            <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
            <MerchantIdentifier>ASHAXSDLATFYG</MerchantIdentifier>
            </Header>
            <MessageType>ProductImage</MessageType><Message> 
                    <MessageID>1</MessageID> 
                    <ProductImage> 
                    <SKU>BG4303</SKU>
                        <ImageType>Main</ImageType>
                     <ImageLocation>http://exmple.com/15203203915886PhotoC3551960-1.jpeg</ImageLocation>

                     <ImageType>PT1</ImageType>
                     <ImageLocation>http://exmple.com/15203203915886PhotoC3551960-1.jpeg</ImageLocation>

                     <ImageType>PT2</ImageType>
                     <ImageLocation>http://exmple.com/15203203915886PhotoC3551960-1.jpeg</ImageLocation>

                     </ProductImage>
                     </Message>
    </AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following xml worked for me, not sure if its proper way or not. I am new to amazon mws as well.

```
<MessageType>ProductImage</MessageType>
    <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace> 
    <Message> 
        <MessageID>1</MessageID> 
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType> 
        <ProductImage> 
            <SKU>BG4303</SKU> 
            <ImageType>Main</ImageType>
            <ImageLocation>http://exmple.com/15203203915886PhotoC3551960-1.jpeg</ImageLocation>
        </ProductImage> 
    </Message>
    <Message> 
        <MessageID>2</MessageID> 
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType> 
        <ProductImage> 
            <SKU>BG4303</SKU> 
            <ImageType>Swatch</ImageType>
            <ImageLocation>http://exmple.com/15203203915886PhotoC3551960-1.jpeg</ImageLocation>
        </ProductImage> 
    </Message>
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the Amazon XSDs and validate using xmllint.

`xmllint --schema {$schema} {$xmlFile} --noout`

XSD List:

https://github.com/crazyfactory/amazon-xsd